# Who was the Irish interpreter in Monterey in 1822?

Tags: language, colonial-america, california, business-history

Kirill Khlebnikov was a Russian business agent who made several visits to Alta California. His "Travel Notes" from 1822 describe Khlebnikov's visit to Governor Sola in Monterey, who sent for "the Irish interpreter". (I think this means that their discussion was held in English.)

Who was the Irish interpreter?

Comment: I think weve already [answered this one](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/34602/which-irishman-worked-at-mission-santa-cruz/34616#34616)

Comment: You think it was the same person? I thought we established that Mulligan was resident in Santa Cruz. There was also some Irish weaver present in California at the time.

Comment: From California Padres:' ... and was a good deal of a nuisance but he was a practical weaver and the Padres used to have him at the different Missions to teach his trade to the neophytes...' concerning Mulligan.

Comment: Good citation. I think I would believe that it was Mulligan if I knew that he had been in Monterey in 1820 or had ever acted as interpreter. By the way, @user2448131, you have been super helpful -- thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently John Mulligan, our Irishman from [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/34602/which-irishman-worked-at-mission-santa-cruz/34616#34616), was a man of many talents( and a couple of names).

From [Forgotten Pioneers: Irish Leaders in Early California](https://books.google.com/books?id=zgf0pN_cA90C&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=mulligan%20monterey%20interpreter&source=bl&ots=FSTBKHI3MC&sig=3bNukZTyD5wAwl_xCy4kWHc2H-E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS4fbyvrTRAhXhgFQKHaTABh4Q6AEIPTAG#v=onepage&q=mulligan%20monterey%20interpreter&f=false)
By Thomas F. Prendergast

> Milligan acted as interpreter, as noted in the State papers

From [The Irish Cultural Directory for Southern California](https://books.google.com/books?id=YDvXAAAAMAAJ&q=milligan%20monterey%20irish%20%20interpreter&dq=milligan%20monterey%20irish%20%20interpreter&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF3OHHwrTRAhUS62MKHTQJBbUQ6AEIJTAC) - Page xvii

> In March 1816, he acted as an interpreter when the captain of the
>   Lydia was tried at Monterey on a charge of smuggling.

From [Indians and Pioneers of Old Monterey](https://books.google.com/books?id=aDUXAAAAIAAJ&q=milligan%20monterey%20irish%20%20interpreter&dq=milligan%20monterey%20irish%20%20interpreter&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF3OHHwrTRAhUS62MKHTQJBbUQ6AEIITAB)

> John Mulligan, or Milligan, the Irish weaver, may have arrived on the
>   same occasion....an Irish resident, appears in 1 8 1 6 as interpreter
>   for some English-speaking visitors.

Comment: Go, Mulligan, go!